# find all the solutions: chinese remainder + fermat theorem

Tags: chinese-remainder-theorem

I have following congruences, in first congruence I know I have to use the Fermat theorem for finding the solution but I couldn't understand how, because most of the samples in internet using some numbers instead of x. 
could somebody please explain it for me in simple way?

1)
$x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$

$3x \equiv 6 \pmod{15}$

2) what about the following case?
$x^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$

by the way I know this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) but as I said it explain by numbers.

Comment: @Timbuc. I know also x2≡1(3)  = x≡(+ - )1(3) and x≡−1(3)=x≡2(3) but why? what about if I have x4≡1(5)?

Comment: You can write $3x\equiv 6  (15)$ in the expanded equivalent form $3x=6+15n$ - can you solve that for $x$

Comment: Note that $3x\equiv6\bmod{15}$ is the same as $x\equiv2\bmod5$.

Answer (score 1):

For (1) You know by fermat's little theorem that $x$ must be coprime with $3$ and so you have $x=1,2$ and so $x  \equiv 1 \pmod 3 \space \textbf{or} \space x \equiv 2 \pmod3$ And you can even try it $1^2 \equiv 1 \pmod3$ $\space$ and $\space $ $2^2 \equiv \pmod 3$

now you have $3x \equiv 6 \pmod{15} $

And since $3,6$ and $15$ are all divisible by $3$ then You can divide the congruence by $3$ to get $x \equiv 2 \pmod5 $ Now how can you use the Chinese remainder theorem ?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is any x =2+5(3k) or x=2+5(1+3k). For the second equation gives 
x-2=5k or x=2+5k and upon squaring we get k=0 or 1 mod 3. The result follows.